# webcam not detected/working - related to video driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, webcam, nouveau

Ubuntu 18.04 recent install constantly updated now with kernel 4.15.0-24-generic on a Dell laptop Latitude E6430.

From what I can tell I have an Nvidea graphics chip NVC1 GF108GLM [NFS 520M] but seems to be running X.Org XServer == Nouveau display driver.

Would switching to the Nvidia 390 driver assist in any way with getting the webcam to work or is that a red herring?

Comment: What made you think the webcam problem is related to your video card driver?

Comment: just some comment elsewhere on the net that suggested that could be the cause.  Are you suggesting that indeed it is a red herring?